# XMLWorker not calling my servlet to render image in pdf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, itext, xmlworker

I am trying to access image from DB and render it in PDF. Below is my servlet to get Image from DB.

```
public class ImageDownloadServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
private  Connection connection = null;
private Statement stmt = null;
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
 try {
Integer imageId=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("imageId").toString());


            connection = //creating connection  
                stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT IMG_BLOB FROM ImageTable WHERE img_id = "+imageId);
        rs.next();
        Blob b=rs.getBlob(1);

        resp.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        resp.setContentLength((int) b.length());
        InputStream is = b.getBinaryStream();
        OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
        byte buf[] = new byte[(int) b.length()];
        is.read(buf);
        os.write(buf);
        os.close();

        stmt.close();
        connection.close();


    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

This code is working fine and i am getting image in CKEditor. But while trying to create PDF this servlet is not being called. My web.xml is
     `<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ImageDownloadServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ImageDownloadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.ImageDownloadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ImageDownloadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/tesing/Image</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

Amd my code to create PDF is

```
File file = new File(D:/satz/sat.pdf);
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
    Document doc=new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 70, 130);
    PdfWriter pdfWriter=PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fos);
    String pdfString="<html><body>hello<img src='/tesing/Image?imageId=1' alt='' /></body></html>";
    doc.open();
    XMLWorkerHelper worker=XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfString.getBytes());
    worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, doc, is);
    doc.close();
```

My problem is while creating the PDF its not calling this servlet. I am using `itextpdf-5.4.4.jar` and `xmlworker-5.4.1.jar` and spring MVC.

**UPDATED** If I use RAD and Tomcat 7.0 server the full path is calling my servlet and generating PDF with image. But when i am using RAD and Websphere 8.5 it's not at all invoking my servlet.

Comment: As an aside: You should try and use identical itextpdf and xmlworker versions.

Comment: Your update makes it sound like a communication issue. You might want to check server logs and create a tcp dump of the different communications between (XmlWorker or CK Editor) and (Websphere or Tomcat) to see what goes wrong. Maybe there is a simple re-direct which is not followed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to parse this HTML

```
String pdfString="<html><body>hello<img src='/tesing/Image?imageId=1' alt='' /></body></html>";
```

Your image source URL does neither include protocol nor host. How should iText know how (which protocol) and where (which host) to request your partial URL.

Thus, use the complete URL instead.

Comment: ya i tried with the full path also. But CK Editor rendering this Image.

Comment: *I tried with the full path also* - by *full path* you mean a complete URL including protocol and host? And what was the result? *But CK Editor rendering this Image.* - as mentioned above, if you don't tell iText how and where to find the image, it cannot know. Maybe *CK Editor* guesses correctly, but that's pure guesswork.

Comment: http://localhost:9082/MarketIntelligence/BBH/MarketIntelligence/Image?imageId=9 this is my full path. This also not working. Ck Editor rendering the image by calling my servlet. But XMLWorker not invoking the servlet. `identical itextpdf and xmlworker versions` means?

Comment: *this is my full path* - hhmmm, that looks ok indeed (you put me on quite the wrong trail by claiming differently in your question). *`identical itextpdf and xmlworker versions` means?* - it means e.g. `itextpdf-5.4.4.jar` and `xmlworker-5.4.4.jar`, or `itextpdf-5.4.1.jar` and `xmlworker-5.4.1.jar`, not a mix like `itextpdf-5.4.4.jar` and `xmlworker-5.4.1.jar`.